# Watching a counter, tally total and counting missed counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, counting

I am attempting to create a piece of code that will watch a counter with an output something like:

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
```

I want the code to be able to tally the total and tell me how many counts are missed for example if this happened:

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,  25, 26,  5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,1,2]
```

I would get a total of 92 still, but get feedback that 8 are missing.

I have gotten very close with the following code:

```
Blk_Tot = 0

CBN = 0
LBN = 0
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
MissedBlocks = 0

for i in range(len(a1)):
    CBN = a1[i]
    if CBN - LBN <= 0:
        if LBN == 30:
            y = 30 - abs(CBN - LBN)
        elif LBN < 30:
            z = 30 - LBN
            y = 30 - abs(CBN - LBN) + z
            print(z)




        Blk_Tot = Blk_Tot + y
    else:
        x = CBN - LBN
        Blk_Tot = Blk_Tot + x
        if x > 1:
            MissedBlocks = MissedBlocks - 1 + x
    LBN = CBN


print(Blk_Tot)

print(MissedBlocks)
```

If I delete anywhere between 1 and 30 it works perfectly, however if I delete across 30, say 29,30,1,2 it breaks.I don't expect it to be able to miss 30 in a row and still be able to come up with a proper total however.

Anyone have any ideas on how this might be achieved? I feel like I am missing an obvious answer :D

Sorry I think I was unclear, a1 is a counter coming from an external device that counts from 1 to 30 and then wraps around to 1 again. Each count is actually part of a message to show that the message was received; so say 1 2 4, I know that the 3rd message is missing. What I am trying to do is found out the total that should have been recieved and how many are missing from the count.

Update after an idea from the posts below, another method of doing this maybe:

Input:

123456

List[1,2,3,4,5,6]

1.Check first input to see which part of the list it is in and start from there (in case we don't start from zero)

2.every time an input is received check if that matches the next value in the array

3.if not then how many steps does it take to find that value

Comment: Sorry I think I was unclear, the count is coming from an external device that counts from 1 to 30 and then wraps around to 1 again. Each count is actually part of a message to show that the message was received; so say 1 2 4, I know that the 4th message is missing. What I am trying to do is found out the total and how many are missing from the count.

Comment: In essence, you want to iterate through the list, compare for values from `1 thru 30` and if any are missing, then count them. Then take the second batch and check until you reach the final batch. Is there a scenario when the sequence will be off? say `1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 8, .... 30` where 3 and 4 were swapped, then 6 and 7 were missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to keep track if you past the 30 line.

Just compare with the ideal sequence and count the missing numbers.

No knowledge if parts missing at the end.

No knowledge if more than 30 parts are missing in a block.

```
from itertools import cycle

def idealSeqGen():
  for i in cycle(range(1,31)):
    yield(i)

def receivedSeqGen():
  a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,
                    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
        1,2]
  for i in a1:
    yield(i)

receivedSeq = receivedSeqGen()
idealSeq = idealSeqGen()

missing = 0
ideal = next(idealSeq)
try:
  while True:
    received = next(receivedSeq)
    while received != ideal:
      missing += 1
      ideal = next(idealSeq)
    ideal = next(idealSeq)
except StopIteration:
  pass

print (f'There are {missing} items missing')
```

---

**Edit**

The loop part can be a little bit simpler

```
missing = 0
try:
  while True:
    ideal = next(idealSeq)
    received = next(receivedSeq)
    while received != ideal:
      missing += 1
      ideal = next(idealSeq)
except StopIteration:
  pass

print (f'There are {missing} items missing')
```

Comment: I can work with that! Thanks! Going to have look more in depth with itertools I think, seems like there's a lot of useful stuff in there.

Comment: @StrangeCalibur I have made the loop part a bit simpler

Comment: Thanks! I very much appreciate it! I need to read up on the except stuff..... like there’s a few different versions and I don’t quite understand them.

Answer (score 0):

## New code to check for missing elements from a repeating sequence pattern

Now that I have understood your question more clearly, here's the code. The assumption in this code is the list will always be in ascending order from 1 thru 30 and then repeats again from 1. There can be missing elements between 1 and 30 but the order will always be in ascending order between 1 and 30.

If the source data is as shown in list `a1`, then the code will result in `8` missing elements.

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,
      5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      1,2]

a2 = a1.copy()

c = 1
missing = 0
while a2:
    if a2[0] == c:
        c+=1
        a2.pop(0)
    elif a2[0] > c:
        missing +=1
        c+=1
    elif a2[0] < c:
        missing += 31-c
        c = 1

    if c == 31: c=1

print (f'There are {missing} items missing in the list')
```

The output of this will be:

```
There are 8 items missing in the list
```

Let me know if this addresses your question

## earlier code to compare two lists

You cannot use `set` as the items are repeated. So you need to `sort` them and find out how many times each element is in both lists. The difference will give you the missing counts. You may have an element in `a1` but not in `a2` or vice versa. So finding out the absolute count of missing items will give you the results.

I will update the response with better variables in my next update.

Here's how I did it:

## code with comments:

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,
      5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,1,2]

#step 1: Find out which list is longer. We will use that as the master list
if len(a1) > len(a2):
    master_list = a1.copy()
    second_list = a2.copy()
else:
    master_list = a2.copy()
    second_list = a1.copy()

#step 2: We must sort both master and second list
#        so we can compare against each other
master_list.sort()
second_list.sort()

#set the counter to zero
missing = 0

#iterate through the master list and find all values in master against second list
#for each iteration, remove the value in master[0] from both master and second list
#when you have iterated through the full list, you will get an empty master_list
#this will help you to use while statement to iterate until master_list is empty
while master_list:
    #pick the first element of master list to search for
    x = master_list[0]
    #count the number of times master_list[0] is found in both master and second list
    a_count = master_list.count(x)
    b_count = second_list.count(x)

    #absolute difference of both gives you how many are missing from each other
    #master may have 4 occurrences and second may have 2 occurrences. abs diff is 2
    #master may have 2 occurrences and second may have 5 occurrences. abs diff is 3
    missing += abs(a_count - b_count)

    #now remove all occurrences of master_list[0] from both master and second list
    master_list = [i for i in master_list if i != x]
    second_list = [i for i in second_list if i != x]

#iterate until master_list is empty

#you may end up with a few items in second_list that are not found in master list
#add them to the missing items list
#thats your absolute total of all missing items between lists a1 and a2

#if you want to know the difference between the bigger list and shorter one,
#then don't add the missing items from second list
missing += len(second_list)

#now print the count of missig elements between the two lists
print ('Total number of missing elements are:', missing)
```

The output from this is:

```
Total number of missing elements are: 7
```

If you want to find out which elements are missing, then you need to add a few more lines of code.

In the above example, elements `27,28,29,30, 4, 5` are missing from `a2` and `31` from `a1`. So total number of missing elements is `7`.

## code without comments:

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,
      5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,1,2]

if len(a1) > len(a2):
    master_list = a1.copy()
    second_list = a2.copy()
else:
    master_list = a2.copy()
    second_list = a1.copy()

master_list.sort()
second_list.sort()

missing = 0

while master_list:
    x = master_list[0]

    a_count = master_list.count(x)
    b_count = second_list.count(x)

    missing += abs(a_count - b_count)

    master_list = [i for i in master_list if i != x]
    second_list = [i for i in second_list if i != x]

missing += len(second_list)
print ('Total number of missing elements are:', missing)
```

Comment: Sorry I think I was unclear, a1 is a counter coming from an external device that counts from 1 to 30 and then wraps around to 1 again. Each count is actually part of a message to show that the message was received; so say 1 2 4, I know that the 3rd message is missing. What I am trying to do is found out the total that should have been recieved and how many are missing from the count.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to compare `list_a1` and `list_a2`, then say which ones from the first list is missing in second list? Are you looking for each set of `[1.... 30]` and see if there are any missing from this list?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to count the number of differences between two lists, you can easily use a dictionary. The other answer would also work, but it is highly inefficient for even slightly larger lists.

```
def counter(lst):
    # create a dictionary with count of each element
    d = {}
    for i in lst:
        if d.get(i, None):
            d[i] += 1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
    return d 

def compare(d1, d2):
    # d1 and d2 are dictionaries
    ans = 0
    for i in d1.values():
        if d2.get(i, None):
            # comapares the common values in both lists
            ans += abs(d1[i]-d2[i])
            d2[i] = 0
        else:
            #for elements only in the first list
            ans += d1[i]
    for i in d2.values():
        # for elements only in the second list
        if d2[i]>0:
            ans += d2[i]
    return ans
    
l1 = [...]
l2 = [...]
print(compare(counter(l1), counter(l2)))
```

Comment: Sorry I think I was unclear, a1 is a counter coming from an external device that counts from 1 to 30 and then wraps around to 1 again. Each count is actually part of a message to show that the message was received; so say 1 2 4, I know that the 3rd message is missing. What I am trying to do is found out the total that should have been recieved and how many are missing from the count.